# Angular 2 beforeEachProviders fail with Injector in tests

Tags: testing, angular, angular2-testing

When I try to pass `Injector` to the `beforeEachProviders` in tests I get the following error.

```
Failed: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Injector'(?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Injector' is decorated with Injectable.
```

The code I use

```
import { Injector } from 'angular2/core';

describe(() => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => [Injector]);
});
```

What is missing? What should I give to the providers to be able to instantiate it?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what your code looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you need to configure `Injector` in your providers for the test. An instance of this class can be directly injected into your test...

Here is what I have in one of my tests (no "explicit" provider for `Injector`) and I'm able to inject it into a test later:

```
import {it, describe, expect, beforeEach, inject, beforeEachProviders} from 'angular2/testing';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, XHRBackend, Response, ResponseOptions} from 'angular2/http';
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from 'angular2/http/testing';
import {provide, Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {HttpService} from "./http-service";

describe('HttpService Tests', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => {
    return [
      HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: MockBackend }),
      HttpService
    ];
  });

  it('Should return a list of dogs', inject(
         [XHRBackend, HttpService, Injector],
         (mockBackend, httpService, injector) => {
    console.log(injector); // <----- Not null
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was i wanted to add it at beforeEachProviders, after i removed it works fine for me also.